# pyspark split mutliple values and assign to different variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

It might be simple question but I am unable to move forward as I just started learning pyspark

I have a hug txt file and it have the following values

```
231838: 232339  
460667: 4967166 387247  
290099: 53729 84707 387247 1593933 2142297 2638860 2795500 2811682 3035561 3048342 3072654 3112123 3277127 3349725 3681900 3893671 4306429 4306431 4847611 4966546 5601388  
392951: 40168 57000 161350 462315 505135 506843 669807 789322 801042 900408 900445 1219904 1574331 1804986 2496688 2511269 2632198 2934273 3211510 3262717 3687835 3822544 3850181 4276958 4302220 4333543 4498476 4926337 5573922 5661442 5697736  
328396: 328397
```

The program should split the values by colon and store it as a ids, and split the text by space and store it as a links, then return ids which is not present in the links.

Each line starts with a page ID, which is followed by a list of all the pages for example before colon(:) is called ID , after colon(:) is called links , the links can be split by space

in python it will be like this but how do I apply sample logic in pyspark

```
ids = []
links = []
result = []

def returnOrphanIds():
  for line in lines:
      str = line.split(":")
      ids.append(str[0])
      links.extend(str[1].split(" "))
  for id in ids:
      if id not in links:
          result.append(id)
return result
```

Comment: read it using [`spark.read.csv("path/to/file", sep=":")`]. Then remove the leading space with [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) and [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two problems to be solved:

1. Parse your input: I'll leave it for you as a task, it's quite simple to do it in Spark, all you need is `trim`, and `split` functions.
2. Remove links from ids column.

at that point I went with exploding `links` column and subtracting it from `id` column.

```
df.select("id").subtract(df.select(F.explode("links")))
```

But I assume this is going to be VERY inefficient (at least gets the job done though). If anybody have suggestions how to solve that more efficiently, I would love to know!